# How to find Popup state and refresh state in React-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I know this question kind a stupid But I am pretty confused with this site producthunt how they are doing this.When clicking the product list popup with react router is done like this..
[image]

But When I refresh that page it render like this..How this is done using React-router
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet would be that they use the [`state` property](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc) when pushing a page to give an indication to the component about how to render the page. More specifically, to indicate the component where it comes from. For example:

```
router.push({
  pathname: '/posts/origami-studio-by-facebook',
  state: { fromPosts: true }
})
```

And then you can read the router's state in the route's component to check what page to show.

```
const Post = (productName) => {
  if(this.context.router.location.state.fromPosts) {
    return <Posts productPopup{productName} /> 
    // open the posts page with a popup for the product
  } else {
    return <PostPage productName={productName} />
  }
}
```

So when you open the page in your browser, the `state.fromPosts` is not set and you get redirected to the PostPage. In the end, even if the route is the same, what you end up seing is completely different.